# Golang execute commands with double quotes

Tags: go, cmd

I made a simple program which takes user input and then executes it as a system command.

**This takes user input and stores it in command variable:**

```
fmt.Print(">  ")
    
scanner := bufio.NewScanner(os.Stdin)
scanner.Scan()
command := scanner.Text()
```

**Then I execute it and print out Stdout aswell as Stderr:**

```
cmd := exec.Command("cmd", "/c", command)

cmd.Stdout = customOutput{}
cmd.Stderr = os.Stderr

if err := cmd.Run(); err != nil {
    fmt.Println("could not run command: ", err)
}
```

Now when I execute command like: ipconfig, arp -a, ping, it all works great and the output is getting printed out as it executes, but when I try to use double quotes in the command it just breaks.

**The problem:**
I tried doing: `echo hello world > file.txt` and this works fine but as soon as I put the filename in quotes: `echo hello world > "file.txt"` I'm getting exit status 1 and from Stderr I'm getting: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.

**I tried:**

- searching, even asking chat-gpt but I can't figure out why this happens.
- replacing the quotes before executing the command to: " or ^" but nothing works.

I'm using windows 10 btw.

**Full code for better understanding:**

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "os/exec"
)

type customOutput struct{}

func (c customOutput) Write(p []byte) (int, error) {
    fmt.Println("received output: ", string(p))
    return len(p), nil
}

func main() {
    fmt.Print(">  ")
    
    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(os.Stdin)
    scanner.Scan()
    command := scanner.Text()

    cmd := exec.Command("cmd", "/c", command)

    cmd.Stdout = customOutput{}
    cmd.Stderr = os.Stderr

    if err := cmd.Run(); err != nil {
        fmt.Println("could not run command: ", err)
    }
}
```

Comment: Those double quotes are processed by the shell, not the command. Just don't put the filename in quotes, or strip the quotes before passing the filename to `Command`.

Comment: But some commands might required quotes, also what if the filename includes spaces?

Comment: The correct syntax is ```cmd.exe /d /c "commandshere"```, (where `commandshere` can include normal doublequoting as necessary). So your exec.Command should probably look more like this: ```("cmd.exe", "/d /c", "\""+command+"\"")```.

Comment: Thanks for replying @Compo but this doesn't change anything in terms of my problem. I try the same command again: echo hello world > "file.txt" and I get the same error. I tried the same exact command: cmd.exe /d /c "echo hello world > "file.txt"" in normal cmd.exe and it does work. Just doesn't in golang for some reason.

Comment: You only need quotes for spaces because of the shell. You're not running this in the shell. It doesn't work the same way as executing it in your shell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do

```
cmd := exec.Command("cmd.exe")
cmd.SysProcAttr = &syscall.SysProcAttr{CmdLine: fmt.Sprintf(`/c "%s"`, command)}
cmd.Stdout = customOutput{}
cmd.Stderr = os.Stderr

if err := cmd.Run(); err != nil {
    fmt.Println("could not run command: ", err)
}
```

and then probably escape the quotes in command.

https://pkg.go.dev/os/exec#Command

> On Windows, processes receive the whole command line as a single string and do their own parsing. Command combines and quotes Args into a command line string with an algorithm compatible with applications using CommandLineToArgvW (which is the most common way). *Notable exceptions are msiexec.exe and **cmd.exe** (and thus, all batch files), which have a different unquoting algorithm. **In these or other similar cases, you can do the quoting yourself and provide the full command line in SysProcAttr.CmdLine, leaving Args empty.**